# ngAfterViewInit called too early

Tags: angular, dom, graph

I am using am4chart and I got an error in my console : `html container not found`.
The line which is causing this error is this line of my angular component :
 `var chart = am4core.create("graphdiv", am4charts.XYChart);`

stacktrace in console :

```
function createChild(htmlElement, classType) {
   var htmlContainer = $dom.getElement(htmlElement);
   if (htmlContainer) {
      ...
   }
   else {
      system.log("html container not found");
      throw new Error("html container not found");
   }
}
```

So basically what I understand is that this line : `var chart = am4core.create("graphdiv", am4charts.XYChart);` is executed BEFORE the graphdiv element exists in the DOM, because it didn't found the graphdiv HTML element.

So what I did is that I copy paste my code which creates the graph into the `ngAfterViewInit` angular function, to make sure that the script which creates my am4chart graph is executed AFTER to make sure that DOM exists before running the script

My afterViewInit function :

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log("CREATE GRAPH AFTER VIEW INIT")
    this.createGraph();
}
```

But what I see is that the console.log("CREATE GRAPH AFTER VIEW INIT") is in fact executed BEFORE that the DOM is fully rendered, so what I did doesn't slve my error `html container not found`

createGraph() :

```
createGraph() {

    console.log("CREATE GRAAAAPH");

    // Create chart instance
    am4core.ready(function() {

      var chart = am4core.create("graphdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
      chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = this.currencyBefore + "#,####,###.##" + this.currencyAfter;

      chart.data = [];
      var cumul = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < 37; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          chart.data.push({ "month": "", "units": 0 });
        } 
        else if (i == 1) {
          cumul = cumul + this.AppComponent.activeDetailedResults.prices.upfrontYear1 + this.AppComponent.activeDetailedResults.prices.monthlyPrice;
          chart.data.push({ "month": "M" + i, "units": cumul });
        } 
        else if (i == 13) {
          cumul = cumul + this.AppComponent.activeDetailedResults.prices.upfrontYear2 + this.AppComponent.activeDetailedResults.prices.monthlyPrice;
          chart.data.push({ "month": "M" + i, "units": cumul });
        } 
        else if (i == 25) {
          cumul = cumul + this.AppComponent.activeDetailedResults.prices.upfrontYear3 + this.AppComponent.activeDetailedResults.prices.monthlyPrice;
          chart.data.push({ "month": "M" + i, "units": cumul });
        } 
        else {
          cumul = cumul + this.AppComponent.activeDetailedResults.prices.monthlyPrice;
          chart.data.push({ "month": "M" + i, "units": cumul });
        }
      }

      // Create axes
      let categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
      categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "month";
      categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true
      categoryAxis.title.text = "Time (36 months)";

      let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
      valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = false;

      // Create series
      var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
      series2.name = "Units";
      series2.stroke = am4core.color("#551A8B");
      series2.strokeWidth = 3;
      series2.dataFields.valueY = "units";
      series2.dataFields.categoryX = "month";
      series2.fillOpacity = 0.5;
    });
  }
```

template :

```
<mat-card class="startcard">
   <p class="mat-title">Cumulative expenses: </p>
   <mat-card-content style="text-align: center;">
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
         <div id="graphdiv"></div>
      </div>
   </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Can you show your component's template? and your `createGraph` method?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce it, but according to this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/bbkxrmbrebl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-fancy-example.ts) it should work. (Not entirely though, because you are using `function() {}` when you should use `() => {}`, but that shouldn't matter for the error). Are you sure you showed the entire template and there is not `*ngIf` around it? You can also try to use a `@ViewChild` and use the `nativeElement` and pass this to the `am4core.create` method

Comment: Another thing is the `ngAfterViewInit` from the same component as where the template belongs to?

Comment: Indeed, i didn't show you my entire template because it has a lot of lines, but indeed, I got a *ngIf condition at the beggining of my template. That's because I do API calls, and I want the DOM to be rendered ONLY IF all API calls are done. That's what my *ngIf is used for.

Comment: And yes ngAfterViewInit is in the component that is linked with the template, for sure without any doubt.

Comment: I changed my code, I am now using `() => { }`

Comment: I tried usiing @ViewChild and use the nativeElement and pass it to am4core.create, but I got an error which is `this.graphDiv is undefined`.           
The view child`@ViewChild('graphdiv', { static: false }) graphDiv: ElementRef<HTMLElement>; ` and how i am creating the chat `var chart = am4core.create(this.graphDiv.nativeElement, am4charts.XYChart);`

Comment: You should move your `this.createGraph();` in the `subscribe` of your API calls. Or if you are using the router, you can use a resolve to have the API resolve before your component is instantiated. Because of that `*ngIf` the element is not available in `ngAfterViewInit` for the simple reason that the API call is not finished yet

Comment: So this is it. Now the function createGraph is call when my API calls are finished ( 3 API calls ). But I still got the error "html container not found"

Comment: Right, that makes sense, because the ViewChild will be visible after the next change detection cycle. So you could wrap it in a `setTimeout` call. But that's a bit hacky. I'll post an answer which will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that the element is not visible at component creation, because you are waiting for API calls. You can make the `ViewChild` a setter:

If this is your template:

```
<mat-card class="startcard">
   <p class="mat-title">Cumulative expenses: </p>
   <mat-card-content style="text-align: center;">
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
         <div #graphdiv></div>
      </div>
   </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

You can make your component the following:

```
private _div?: HTMLElement;

@ViewChild('graphdiv')
set graphDiv(div: ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
  if (div && div.nativeElement && this._div !== div.nativeElement) {
    this._div = div.nativeElement;
    this.createGraph();
  }
}

createGraph() {
  am4core.ready(() => {
    const chart = am4core.create(this._div, am4charts.XYChart);
  });
}
```

This way you don't have to do it in the `ngAfterViewInit` hook or after the API call. It will be done automatically

Comment: Thank you it helped me a lot

Comment: By making the ViewChild a setter, what benefit did we get? I apologize if it's a naive question but I'm still learning Angular

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move your code to `ngAfterViewChecked` method. As another try is to use `setTimeout` with 0 time and your code inside.